# Windows 10 Mobile Insider Preview Build 10536 installed, but system does not start

Tags: insider-preview

I just installed a preview build. I guess it was the latest one which is Build 10536. My Lumia 435 is one of the phone on the list of to-support-Windows 10 Mobile from early one. but, after installation, when I press the power button to start it, Microsoft logo shows up, then Windows 8 logo over it before even Microsoft logo disappears, then gears show up reeling, while no progress is shown below the gears. Phone reboots repeatedly, Microsoft logo appears, then Windows logo, then the gears, and so on.
Is my phone dead? Is there a way to make it start so I can see how Windows 10 looks?
As a last resort, if the installation cannot be repaired, how can I roll back to my preview Windows Phone 8.1 Update 2?

Update: in order to hard-reset the phone I followed [this](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp8/settings-and-personalization/reset-my-phone) and my phone showed Microsoft logo several times before showing a black screen with a gear and thunder on it, pas in the following figure:
[image]

But the screen is frozen, not showing any movement.

Comment: Try holding Volume-Down+Power.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try a hard reset by pressing the Power, Volume Down, and Camera buttons until the phone vibrates. Then release the power button and keep the other two pressed for 5 seconds. More info [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/wiki/mdlumia-mdsettings/how-to-soft-and-hard-reset-your-windows-phone/4ec36474-c21e-4aec-ad1b-30f3afaf824d). If that doesn't work, you can try the [Windows Phone Recovery Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/support/faq/?action=singleTopic&topic=FA142987). If that still doesn't work, you may need to either send your phone in to be repaired or get a new phone.

Comment: Excuse me, how can I do a hard reset?

Comment: Edited to include that.